# How to get the real address of tabbed page in HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Good Day Guys,

I just want to ask if how will I be able to get the real address in my tabbed form in in HTML/CSS.
right now I can only redirect to tabbed which is pre-set as active.

My goal is to create a link that will direct me to other tabbed page. for example, from other page want to create a link that will direct me to tabbed page `2nd tab` .

here's my code:

```
<div class="tabs">
<ul class="tab-links">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Pending</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Approved</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Completed</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
        <!--Codes here -->
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
        <!--Codes here -->
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab">
        <!--Codes here -->
    </div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab">
        <!--Codes here -->
    </div>
    </div>
```

in the address bar it only shows this even I clicked other tab. stay with this address:

> /domain/beta/page_home_superadmin.php

but in the lower side of the browser, it shows this when I hover at tab2:

> /domain/beta/page_home_superadmin.php#tab2

any suggestion on how will to get that address and a be able to create a link pointing to it.

Thanks.

Comment: not clear what you want to do with address. Not hard to get `href` of the `active` tab

Comment: /domain/beta/page_home_superadmin.php#tab2, this is your answer read this line again. this is the way to create link on the same page. If there is some thing else you are asking you need to clear your question

Comment: /domain/beta/page_home_superadmin.php#tab2, yes I use this address but it didn't direct to  tab2.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use document.location.hash

```
<div class="tabs">
<ul class="tab-links">
    <li class="active tab1" id="tab1"><a href="#tab1">All</a></li>
    <li class="tab2"><a href="#tab2">Pending</a></li>
    <li class="tab3"><a href="#tab3">Approved</a></li>
    <li class="tab4"><a href="#tab4">Completed</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="tab1" class="tab active">
    <!--Codes here -->
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab">
    <!--Codes here -->
</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab">
    <!--Codes here -->
</div>
<div id="tab4" class="tab">
    <!--Codes here -->
</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( document.location.hash ) {
        $('.tab-links > li, div.tab').removeClass('active');
        $('li' + document.location.hash.replace('#', '.') 
          + ', div' + document.location.hash).addClass('active');
    }
});
```